# Not able to install unzip tool in my container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos, dockerfile, centos7

I try to install `unzip` in my `centos` container.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM centos
...

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
```

When I build the image, I get the error:

```
Step 9/12 : RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
 ---> Running in 65457527bac0
/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found
```

How can I install unzip tool in my container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using CentOs the default package manager is not apt-get but instead yum.

So doing this is what your dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM centos
...

RUN yum update
RUN yum install unzip
```

As a more detailed explanation you can remember this:

`apt-get` is the default package manager for debian based distributions of Linux like Ubuntu and a bunch of others.
`yum` is the default package manager for RPM based distributions ( Redhat package manager )

Comment: I need to leave my desk, your answer is correct. I will accept it later since there is a time limit for allowing accepting the answer. Thanks!